# AngularJS: reset $timeout for each page switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my first AngularJS project and I'm working on a timeout that redirects the user to the startpage after a few minutes if they haven't clicked on anything. timeout is called on each page load to restart the timeout.

But the my problem is that restart() is called multiple times. One time for each page/view load. I use ngRoute.
For example if has clicked on three pages, timeout() has now been called three times and when the $timeout reaches the time, restart() is called three times.

```
myapp.controller(..., [...], function(...) {

    function restart() {
        $location.path("/slide/1");
    }

    function timeout() {
        var timeoutHandle = $timeout(function() {

            $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandle);
            restart();

        }, timeoutTime);
    }

    timeout();
}
```

Comment: timeoutHandle() - remove timeout as I know

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
var redirectTimeout;

var redirect = function() {
    $location.path("/slide/1");
}    

$timeout.cancel(redirectTimeout);

redirectTimeout = $timeout(function() {
    var timeoutTime = 5000 // five seconds
    redirectTimeout = $timeout(redirect, timeoutTime);
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomepejo/wk57c/)

Comment: Seems to be the same issue. redirect() is called multiple times. Forgot to mention that I use ngRoute for pages.

Comment: I "temporarly" solved it with this:
    
    $interval(function() {
        
        if(timer >= timeoutTime) {
            redirect();
            timer = 0;
        }

        timer = timer+100;
    }, 100);

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to put this kind of functionality inside a factory?